# Probability of winning multiple games

Tags: probability

I would like to know a formula for the probability of winning a certain number of games.

What is the probability of me winning 2 games if I have a 1/3 chance of winning each time and I play 5 times?

What is the probability of me winning 2 or more games if I have a 1/3 chance of winning each time and I play 5 times?

Those are specific cases. I would like to know if there is a general formula for both.

Comment: why don't you just say you have a $1/3$ chance of winning each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the probability of winning a particular game is $p$. You can win $m$ games out of $n$ games you played in $\binom{n}{m}$ ways, and you have to lose the remaining $n-m$ games. The probability of losing a particular game is obviously $1-p$. Then the probability that you win $m$ games out of $n$ games is
$$\binom{n}{m}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}$$
The probability that you win $m$ or more games among $n$ games is then given by
$$\sum_{t\geq m}\binom{n}{t}p^t(1-p)^{n-t}$$
Now put $n=5,m=2,p=1/3$, to get your answers.

For further reference see the book [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Theory-Applications-Edition/dp/0471257087](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471257087) and look for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution